# Custom interlacing of left and right eyes

Tags: stereoscopy

I have a custom 3D display which requires custom interlacing of left and right eyes images.

How can I customize the interlace stereo mode on Blender? Do I have to rely on python scripts?

Comment: What display do you have? Most displays support the side-by-side placement. Double check the display's settings

Comment: The display requires interlacing of left and right eye images. This interlacing however is very specific.